# Hiding folders that start with dot in Project Explorer in RCP Project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

In my RCP project, I would like to programmatically hide the folders that starts with dot in the *Project Explorer* (when the user browse to open a file).

I have used the below extensions to achieve this, but sadly it did not work. Can someone help? Thank You.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
    <commonFilter
        description="Hides .* resources"
        id="com.xyz.commonFilter.hidePj"
        name=".* resources"
        activeByDefault="true">
        <filterExpression>
            <and>
                <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
                    <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value=".*"/>
                </adapt>
            </and>
        </filterExpression>
    </commonFilter>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
    <viewerContentBinding
          viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
          <includes>
           <contentExtension pattern="com.xyz.commonFilter.hidePj"/> 
          </includes>
    </viewerContentBinding>
</extension>
```

**Note:** I am using eclipse Ganymede.

Comment: Which OS is that?

Comment: What 'File Explorer'? What you have show is for 'Project Explorer' - is that what you are using?

Comment: Windows operating System. Yes @greg-449, it is project explorer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I edited the question. Can you please have a look?

Comment: In `Project Explorer` if you click the arrow in the top right corner you can select `Customize View`, there you can select `.* resources` to hide resources that starts with a dot; is this what you are looking for?

Comment: No, I need to programmatically hide the "folders" that starts with dot.

Answer (score 2):

Change the generic `IResource` type:

```
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IResource">
```

and use the most specific `IFolder` type:

```
<adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
```

The relevant source code follows, standard Eclipse plugin project created with the wizard (Ganymede), I just changed the `id` name attribute:

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>

  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
    <commonFilter
        id="com.stackoverflow.commonFilter.hideFolders"
        name=".* folders"
        description="Hides .* folders"
        activeByDefault="true">
      <filterExpression>
        <and>
            <adapt type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFolder">
              <test property="org.eclipse.core.resources.name" value=".*"/>
            </adapt>
        </and>
      </filterExpression>
    </commonFilter>
  </extension>

  <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.viewer">
    <viewerContentBinding viewerId="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.ProjectExplorer">
      <includes>
        <contentExtension pattern="com.stackoverflow.commonFilter.hideFolders" /> 
      </includes>
    </viewerContentBinding>
  </extension>

</plugin>
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Filter_dot Plug-in
Bundle-SymbolicName: filter_dot;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.5
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.navigator,org.eclipse.core.resources
```

build.properties:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               plugin.xml
```

In the following images the "Project Explorer" displays a ".test" folder, if the filter is enabled, using the "Arrow in the top right corner > Customize View..." option, then the folder is hidden.

[image: Eclipse plugin]

Comment: It still does not work with this fix. When I browse to open a file on the editor, the folders that start with dot are still visible. Do I need to define any class somewhere?

Comment: @TravelingSalesman I have updated the answer with the full source code. The filter is working fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your work, but on the line visibleInUI="false", I am getting a warning: illegal attribute.

Comment: By the way, I am using eclipse Ganymede.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman Ganymede? 10 years old release? That is a relevant information that must be part of the question. Otherwise latest Eclipse release is assumed.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not know that it matters. I made the update in my question now.

Comment: @TravelingSalesman I have updated the answer for using Ganymede, still working fine for me.